# How do I allow changes to the way methods are called without recompiling each time?

Tags: c#, .net

NOTE:  Apologies in advance if this question may not be the clearest, however I am trying to accomplish something but do not have the knowledge necessary to express my idea in it's fullest. I posted here in hopes to learn more advanced way to accomplish my idea.

I have multiple objects that follow an interface like this

```
interface IObj{

 void Parse(string document)    

 string Read(string locationId)
 void Write(string locationId, string valuetoWrite)

}
```

These objects all are representing text document structures.  Some can be CSV format, another object can be XML, and so on.

```
 ObjectA : IObj{ 
 //for example lets say this object represent comma separated values record

 List<string> fields; //list of columns and their values

 void Parse(string input){ //takes the document as string and creates the object representation
     fields.AddRange(input.Split(',');
 }

 Dictionary<string,ObjAlocation> locations;  //maps the locations to an ID

 public string Read(string id){
    //objectA implementation of read
    //knows how to read from ObjALocation only - it takes the correct location that is stored in the dictionary by id and parses it

        string result = string.Empty;

        if (locations.ContainsKey(id))
        {
            ObjALocation position = locations[id];
            if (position.Field <= fields.Count-1)
                result = fields[position.Field];
        }

        return result;
 }

 public void write(string locationId, string valuetoWrite){
    //objectA implementation of write
    //knows how to write to ObjALocationOnly
 }
}



class ObjALocation{  //definition of a location for ObjectA

    public int Field;

}
```

These objects and others like them are arriving to a processing method one at a time. For each of the different objects I process, I read instruction from a configuration XML for that object. The instructions are simple Read or Write to the object.

```
  <String Type="ObjectA">
    <ObjALocation id="1" Field="2" />
    <ObjALocation id="2" Field="4" />
    <ObjALocation id="3" Field="6" />
  </String>

  <Processor Name="ReadValue" Type="ObjectA">
    <Read resultid="1" locationid="1"></Read>
    <Read resultid="2" locationid="2"></Read>
    <Read resultid="3" locationid="4"></Read>

    <Output Path="C:\">
      <Filename extension="csv">
        <![CDATA[output]]>
      </Filename>
      <outputString>
         <result id="1"/> , <result id="2"/> \r\n
      </outputString>
    </Output>
  </Processor>
```

But say tomorrow the user wants to modify the configuration file in this way to read and write in a different order,

```
  <String Type="ObjectA">
    <ObjALocation id="1" Field="12" />
    <ObjALocation id="2" Field="34" />
    <ObjALocation id="3" Field="45" />
  </String>

  <Processor Name="ReadValue" Type="ObjectA">
    <Read resultid="1" locationid="12"></Read>
    <Read resultid="2" locationid="34"></Read>
    <Write resultid="3" locationid="4">
        string to write
    </Write>
.....
  </Processor>
```

In my application I guess I will need a main method called Process() where I will execute all the instruction defined in the XML configuration.

So for example something like this

```
void Processor(){

   Read();
   Read();
   Write();

}
```

However normally you would have to predefine the instruction before compiling the application.  So the methods and their order would be fixed in the Processor() method.  But I don't want to hardcode the instruction to call the read and write method. I want to give end user the ability to call these methods in any order and combination they want. (By modification of the XML configuration, or using a GUI)

So that I don't have to recompile the program every time we need to change the instruction.

EDIT: Is there a way to do it using any of the c# keywords like Func, Action or dynamic. I'm trying to avoid using dynamic code compile option.

There are two issues for me that go together, 
How to get the read and write instances into the Processor() method like above.  **AND** also how to get them into the Processor() method in a dynamic way each time I call Processor() - because tomorrow Processor() could be processing for a totally different object with different configuration of read() and write().

Comment: You should not delete and re-ask your question just because it has been closed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28865578/how-do-i-write-code-to-allow-changes-to-the-way-methods-are-called-without-recom

Comment: @Servy why not ask to clarify instead of closing so fast?

Comment: @Servy i dont understand what is unclear about the question

Comment: Closing an unclear question allows it to be improved and clarified without burdening it with low quality answers due to its lack of clarity.

Comment: That doesn't make it appropriate to just keep re-posting it over and over.

Comment: @Servy  I'm not sure what to do.  it is frustrating, this is the only way I know how to express my question

Comment: Post samples of your implementations of read and write.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I don't want to hardcode the instruction to call the read and write method."

Comment: How do you plan on writing c# code without using any of the c# keywords? Do you mean you don't want the configuration file itself to be c#? Note that `Action` and `Func` aren't keywords, they are [library types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dustinmoris Normally you would have a function that calls the read or write in some order.  It is fixed at compile time.  I will edit to elaborate on this.

Comment: What do `resultid` and `locationid` have to do with `string Read()` and `void write()`? How do you plan on passing a `string to write` to `void write()`?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to get empty, dumb classes to be populated with functionality at runtime from configuration data. Is this the case?

Comment: @Cirdec I will edit to clarify that. thx

Comment: If you are trying to ask how to do a step once for each step in the configuration file in the order they are in the file, you need to include how the configuration file is deserialized (or at least what type it is deserialized to) and your existing code to call the `Read`s.

Answer (score 2):

For input

```
<Root>  
    <Processor Name="ReadValue" Type="ObjectB">
        <Read resultid="1" locationid="12"></Read>
        <Read resultid="2" locationid="34"></Read>
        <Write resultid="3" locationid="4">
            string to write
        </Write>
    </Processor>
    <Processor Name="ReadValue" Type="ObjectA">
        <Read resultid="1" locationid="12"></Read>
        <Read resultid="2" locationid="34"></Read>
        <Write resultid="3" locationid="4">
            string to write
        </Write>
    </Processor>
</Root>
```

your code can look like this:

```
void Main()
{
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\PathToXml\instructions.xml");

    foreach (var processor in xDoc.Root.Elements())
    {
        if (processor.Attribute("Name").Value == "ReadValue")
        {
            var readValueProcessor = new ReadValueProcessor();
            readValueProcessor.Execute(processor);
        }
    }
}

interface IObj
{
    string Read(int resultid, int locationid);
    void Write(int resultid, int locationid, string text);
}

class ObjectA : IObj
{
    public string Read(int resultid, int locationid)
    {
        return resultid + " " + locationid + " From A";
    }

    public void Write(int resultid, int locationid, string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resultid + " " + locationid + " From A : " + text);
    }
}

class ObjectB : IObj
{
    public string Read(int resultid, int locationid)
    {
        return resultid + " " + locationid + " From B";
    }

    public void Write(int resultid, int locationid, string text)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(resultid + " " + locationid + " From B : " + text);
    }
}

class ReadValueProcessor
{
    public void Execute(XElement processorNode)
    {
        var typeAttribute = processorNode.Attribute("Type").Value;
        IObj objectToExecute = null;

        if (typeAttribute == "ObjectA")
        {
            objectToExecute = new ObjectA();
        }
        else if (typeAttribute == "ObjectB")
        {
            objectToExecute = new ObjectB();
        }

        foreach (var action in processorNode.Elements())
        {
            if (action.Name == "Read")
            {
                var resultid = int.Parse(action.Attribute("resultid").Value);
                var locationid = int.Parse(action.Attribute("locationid").Value);
                var result = objectToExecute.Read(resultid, locationid);
                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            else if (action.Name == "Write")
            {
                var resultid = int.Parse(action.Attribute("resultid").Value);
                var locationid = int.Parse(action.Attribute("locationid").Value);
                var text = action.Value;
                objectToExecute.Write(resultid, locationid, text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it gives me something to try out.  I probably would keep the deserializing of the XML separate from the processing.  I.e. I probably wouldn't call processor at each xml element  I would deserialize to objects and use that in the processor.

Comment: @erotavlas sure, you definitely should separate these steps. I just gave you a simplified example of the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a feature called [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

You can get the runtime information about the type of an object by calling it's `GetType()` method. You can then get a specific method from the `Type` by calling [`GetMethod(string name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`GetMethods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Once you have the [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.MethodInfo(v=vs.110).aspx) for the method you wish to call, you can invoke it with its [`Object Invoke(Object, [Object])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh(v=vs.110).aspx) method. The first argument to `Invoke` is the object on which to invoke the method, and the second argument is an array of arguments to pass to the method.

It would be wise to protect your code from executing arbitrary methods by marking those methods that can be executed from a configuration file with an [`Attribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) and checking that the attribute is present before invoking the method.

Comment: I don't think he is looking for reflection. Essentially, his xml just contains an order and arguments for methods he already has implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and for pointing out about using attributes to prevent unwanted method calls